# Access Security level (ACL) with Java EE 6?

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6

I am developing a web application where there are few roles like Admin,Reporter,Manager,Customer.Agent.Based on Role, some menu item need to be displayed . Admin can give permission (dynamically) to user say Agent ( which is not default permission ).Is there a better way to handle this situation ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have some controller which is responsible for permission logic. You would have a permission system where you can grant specific permissions to specific users / groups. The controller could be implemented as a jsf managed bean. You could have a method like this:

```
public boolean hasPermission(PermissionKey permissionKey) {
...
}
```

This method would check role + specific permissions.

PermissionKey, in this example, would be an enum, but you can make it a string or something else. Possible values would be, for example, "DELETE_ACCOUNT" or "HANDLE_PAYMENT".

In your views, you can just conditionnaly display components like this:

```
<h:outputText value="some text" rendered="#{authController.hasPermission('DELETE_ACCOUNT')}" />
```